# Using Python/Elasticsearch package to clone a index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

So there is instruction on clone ES index: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clone-index.html.

But I can't find it how to do it using the Python/elasticsearch package. Can someone show example please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are one API call way, as [per the doc](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.0.0/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.clone)

This should look like:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

client = Elasticsearch(....)

index="index-1"
target="index-1-cloned"

client.indices.clone(index, target)
```